# Cannot build apk file of ionic 1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I cannot build android apk file of ionic 1. When i run

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

it shows me:

> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --release (exit code 1):
>
> Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used. Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap.

[image: Here is my screenshot]

Comment: did you try removing the platform and adding it ?

Comment: yes i did but, still i cannot build it. :(

Answer (score 0):

I can see that it mentioned "unrecognized jvm option"
Check number IV) maybe you didn't upgrade the env variables for the new downloaded jdk. Maybe the jvm doesn't point to the jdk.1.8 you using,it could be pointing to an older one.

Please check these steps if there something missing.

**I. Development  environment  dependencies**

1)You need at Least to download a java JDK 8

2)Download an Android SDK manager

3)you must Add them to the environment variables

(Windows)

i)Open environment variables

ii)ANDROID_HOME:create a new user variable with name ANDROID_HOME and add the path of the SDK manager 
ex.C:\xxx\Android\sdk

iii)edit the user variable PATH value and add to it platform tools path ex. C:\xxx\Android\sdk\platform-tools

iV)JAVA_HOME:Don't forget also to edit in the user variable PATH, your old JAVA_HOME env path with the new JDK Path . ex.C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144

4)Globally install ionic and cordova

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

**II. Ionic CLI for build android**

5)`ionic cordova platform add android`

6)`ionic cordova build android`

**N.B:** there sometimes logging in issue through CLI when using this command, the next steps doesn't really make sense but it worked for me.

```
ionic config set backend pro -g
```

Retry the build process again ,if Still there a problem change to legacy and Then again back to pro

```
ionic config set backend legacy -g

ionic config set backend pro -g
```

It should work now, retry the build process again.

If still there a problem then make an app through the website of ionic
use this command with  the --pro-id  of your app and retry again.

```
ionic start --pro-id <ID>
```